# problem with composer on magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer, command-line, auth.json

I want to setup new extension with composer on magento2 and I get this error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json', aborting.
```

I use public key and private key as user and password ( get key from **`marketplace.magento.com`** )

I use this comment for install new extension:

```
composer require mageplaza/composer require mageplaza/magento-2-seo-extension
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want you to try two things:

1. Do you have more than one pair of public and private key enabled? If
   yes then try by enabling just one and disable all else.
2. **Create auth.json**:

   To create **`auth.json`**:

   - Log in to your Magento server as, or switch to, the Magento file system owner.
   - Edit or create **`auth.json`** in the user’s home directory.

     The following example shows how to add repo.magento.com authentication to an existing file:

> ```
> {
>    "github-oauth": {
>      "github.com": "<your github oauth id>"
>    },
>    "http-basic": {
>       "repo.magento.com": {
>          "username": "<public key>",
>          "password": "<private key>"
>       }
>    }
> }
> ```

**Source:** http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/dev_install.html#create-authjson

Answer (score 2):

TLDR;
=> **enter public key as Username and private key as Password**

I get here with similar problem / refresh topic.
I want to try install magento first time.
Following this [start guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/composer.html)

Using this composer command give me auth error:

```
create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <install-directory-name>
```

[image]

I registered to magento and i generate Api keys. But composer command was prompt for username so i try my user name which Magento generate for me, i tried my username and this public key and all this attempts ends with auth error.

Finnally i tried **paste public key as Username**
and private key as Password and it works like a charm : )

[image]

Hope i help somebody

Answer (score 2):

If someone still has trouble with getting magento 2 through composer because of authentication keys issue as given below, then make sure to update your **`auth.json`** with your **Magento Authentication Keys** (generated from marketplace.magento.com) inside your **COMPOSER_HOME** directory and then exit from your terminal / bash / shell and reopen it and try `composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2/` command again to get Magento.

**Detailed step by step instructions are given below:**

**Generate Authentication Keys inside your Magento Makeplace Account**

https://marketplace.magento.com/customer/accessKeys/

**Find your local machine composer home directory by typing the command below. It shows your composer path.**

```
composer config --list --global | grep 'home'
```

In Windows 10 its like

C:/Users/youruser/AppData/Roaming/Composer

**Open the auth.json inside the Composer Home directory (in a text-editor)**

**Update the file with your keys like given below**

```
{
    "bitbucket-oauth": {},
    "github-oauth": {},
    "gitlab-oauth": {},
    "gitlab-token": {},
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "<your_public_key>",
            "password": "<your_private_key>"
        }
    },
    "bearer": {}
}
```

**Exit the bash / shell / terminal and reopen it again and try the composer command to get the Magento package now. It will work.**

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <your_magento2_install_dir>/
```

BTW my Composer version is 2.x. and am on Windows 10

```
$ composer --version
Composer version 2.0.8 2020-12-03 17:20:38
```

Hope this Helps !